# Server not getting duplicate ACKs

Tags: tcp, wireshark, raw-sockets

I am using raw sockets to communicate with a TCP server. For the purposes of my project, I need to emulate a TCP timeout.

Whenever a timeout occurs, server re-transmits the first lost packet. On receiving ACK for this packet, the sever re-transmits the second packet and also sends a packet that was previously unseen (due to F-RTO algorithm). In order to stop F-RTO, I need to send duplicate ACK for the later packet.

Lets says the congestion window is 20 at the time of time out. Server will send packet 1 and I will ACK packet 1. Server will then send packet 2 and packet 21. I will ACK packet 2 and send duplicate ACK for packet 21 to stop F-RTO. The problem that I am having is that although client is sending 2 ACKs, for some unknown reasons server is only getting one ACK. As a results it gets stuck in F-RTO.

Wireshark shows client sends multiple duplicate ACKs but from server side I can only see a single ACK. Since the second ACK is duplicate to first one, their fields and checksums are same. Can some one please help me out?

Comment: Are the client and server on the same subnet?  Are you running wireshark on both ends?  Are you sure that the IP and TCP checksums are correct?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Client and servers are on different subnets and I am running wireshark on both ends. IP and TCP checksums are correct, a shown by wireshark. TCP checksums for dup acks are similar.

Comment: If it's a duplicate ACK, unless the IP ID has changed, the checksum should be the same.  So you are saying that the duplicate ACKs aren't making it to the server?  That smacks of a checksum problem.

Comment: The IP IDs are different, but isn't this only affect IP checksum? TCP checksums should be similar?

Comment: I also suspect this to be a checksum problem but wireshark shows that checksums are calculated correctly.

Comment: The TCP checksum is a pseudo-header checksum, but that will not prevent a router from passing the packet; only the IP checksum will.  Are you certain that you have IP checksum calculation validation enabled in Wireshark?

Comment: Yes, its enabled. That's why I am puzzled at this behavior.